# vertical alignment symbols from two different equations

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

I would like to align equations from two different lines.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
$$ a = b +1 = c +2 = d +3$$
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs.
$$ a = b$$ 
\end{document}
```

This sample document centers the equations separately.  I would like to have the math-mode symbols `a = b` to align vertically.

[image]

Comment: Use `align` or `align*` environment then, for example? ;-) See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to?s=1|1.6833 please

Comment: Also, if you want the text inbetween the equations, use `\intertext{...}` or `\shortintertext{...}`.

Comment: Are you sure that you really mean 'vertical' alignment?

Comment: Try: `\begin{align*}
a &= b +1 = c +2 = d +3\\
\intertext{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs.}
a &= b
\end{align*}`

Comment: Never use `$$` in LaTeX, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Answer (score 2):

Two 'equivalent' ways, effectively

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
   a &= b + 1   &{}= c + 2 &= d + 3 \\
   \shortintertext{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs.}
   a &= b   
\end{alignat*}

\begin{align*}
   a &= b + 1   = c + 2 = d + 3 \\
   \shortintertext{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs.}
   a &= b   
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should add a `{}` before the 2nd = sign on the first line, or replace the 2nd and 3rd `&=` with `&&=`.

Comment: @Bernard: Yes, you're right, does improve the look. I will change the code here and the image. Thanks!

Comment: Or `&&=` to get to the next left aligned column; but I don't see why using `alignat` when a simple `align` works.

Comment: @egreg: True, just as an alternative...

Comment: @egreg: The second line might include other alignment points.