# Vertical alignment several labeled equations (can be referenced later) at not-consecutive lines

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

In the following situation, I want to vertical align the equal signs `=` in labeled (H) and (NH) equations (so they can be referenced later using `\eqref`) at not-consecutive lines. How could I do it?

The way in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258929/vertical-alignment-symbols-from-two-different-equations) does not work for using `\eqred` later.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\begin{document}
Consider the {\itshape homogeneous} linear differential equation
\begin{equation}
    \tag{H}
    \label{eq:H2}
    y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0
\end{equation}
and {\itshape nonhomogeneous} linear differential equation
\begin{equation}
    \tag{NH}
    \label{eq:NH2}
    y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=f(x)
\end{equation}
where $p(\cdot)$, $q(\cdot)$, and $f(\cdot)$ be continuous functions on some open interval $(a,b)$. The homogeneous equation \eqref{eq:H2} always have a solution $y=0$ called {\itshape the trivial solution}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Follow Campa's answer `\intertext`, I found an involving link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49537/putting-equations-in-intertext-to-annotate-a-proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `align` with `\intertext` (both features of `amsmath`)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\begin{document}
Consider the \textit{homogeneous} linear differential equation
\begin{align}
    \tag{H}
    \label{eq:H2}
    y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y &= 0
\intertext{and \textit{nonhomogeneous} linear differential equation}
    \tag{NH}
    \label{eq:NH2}
    y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y &= f(x)
\end{align}
where $p(\cdot)$, $q(\cdot)$, and $f(\cdot)$ be continuous functions on some
open interval $(a,b)$. The homogeneous equation \eqref{eq:H2} always have a
solution $y=0$ called \textit{the trivial solution}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

(I replaced `{\itshape...}` by `\textit{...}` but that's just my taste.)

Comment: Thank you very much! that is exactly what I need.